# adding additional data to req.user with passport-google-oauth

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, google-oauth

I have a route which meant to authenticate the user using google oauth passport strategy ,(`/auth/google`) I also want to pass additional data as query in the url in that route (`/auth/google?someParam=SOME_PARAM`) , this data I want to add to `req.user` by the time I get it back from google in (`/auth/google/callback`). The problem is that I have access to this query through `/auth/google` but google will redirect me to `/auth/google/callback` which dont have access to this data anymore.

note - Because of design limitation I cant do it with external source as database.

passport-google [docs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/google/)

CODE :

```
// auth.js 

router.get(
  "/",
  (req, res, next) => {
    let siteName = req.query.siteName;
    let pageName = req.query.pageName;
    console.log("siteName", siteName);
    return next();
  },
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"]
  })
);

module.exports = router;




// authCb.js

router.get(
  "/",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"],
    failureRedirect: "/"
  }),
  (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.user);
    res.send(req.user);
  }
);

module.exports = router;





// app.js

app.use("/auth/google", auth);
app.use("/auth/google/callback", authCb);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to store your params in session before sending auth request to google.
Then, after redirect, get your params back from session.

```
// auth.js 
router.get(
  "/",
  (req, res, next) => {
    req.session.lastQuery = req.query;
    return next();
  },
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"]
  })
);

module.exports = router;

// authCb.js

router.get(
  "/",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"],
    failureRedirect: "/"
  }),
  (req, res) => {
    const { lastQuery } = req.session;
    console.log(lastQuery);
  }
);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: thank you! I will try it out and let you know how it went (:

Answer (score 3):

You should refer to Google's documentation. You can use the "state" parameter to pass any data you want to get back once the user is back to your site. This is the main use of this parameter. 
You can see the details [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#creatingclient).

Comment: Is the API works like that: `/auth/google?state=state_value` ? because the docs aren't clear about it. Also they haven't specified how can I access this data later? Sorry if there is obvious answer I just can't see it

Comment: The state={whatever value you sent} is appended to the redirect_uri. So when the user is sent back to your site, you can access it from the URI parameters.